# How to print Array of Objects

Tags: java

I'm having trouble printing a simple array of objects. This is my code:

```
class employ{
String name;
int age;
String date;
public employ(String x, int y, String z) {
    name=x;
    age=y;
    date=z;
}
class ClassandObjects {
public static void main(String[] args){
    employ[] a;
    a=new employ[10];
    a[0]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[1]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[2]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[3]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[4]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[5]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[6]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[7]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[8]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    a[9]= new employ("blah",20,"12-12-2000");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}}
```

I am just trying to print the simple array of objects a. My output looks like:
employ@70dea4e
employ@5c647e05
employ@33909752
employ@55f96302
employ@3d4eac69
employ@42a57993
employ@75b84c92
employ@6bc7c054
employ@232204a1
employ@4aa298b7

Comment: Override `toString()` of `employ`. Eg: `public String toString() { return String.format("Name: %s, Age: %d, Date: %s", name, age, date) }`

Comment: Since you are a "Java_Beginner" please notice that usually class name are written in CamelCase, so your class should be called `Employ`, not `employ`

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes sense.